# a xll for Excel create in vs2008 do not work in computers than the one which was create

Tags: excel, xll

I create a xll file in a computer with vs2008 and Excel 2010. It works perfect on the computer, but when I try to use in a different computer it does not work and excel say tahn the format is not correct. Please can anybody tell me a solution for it. It drive me creasy, it tried almost everything

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are dynamically linking to the C/C++ runtime, and so you need to corresponding redistributable loaded on the other machine.

Alternatively you can statically link to the C/C++ runtime.

If there is an error in the .xll startup, for example a .dll that you need is not found, then Excel will report this with the 'file is not in a valid format...' message.

Comment: OK thanks, You are rigth, i made a setup file for my project including the dll. Thanks